# Returning an error from HandlerFunc - need a new type

Tags: go

Right now I have this:

```
type AppError struct{
   Status int
   Message string
}

func (h NearbyHandler) makeUpdate(v NearbyInjection) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        item, ok := v.Nearby[params["id"]]

        if !ok {
            return AppError{
                500, "Missing item in map.",
            }
        }

   }
}
```

the problem is that if I do this:

```
func (h NearbyHandler) makeUpdate(v NearbyInjection) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) AppError { // <<< return AppError

    }
}
```

that won't compile b/c http.HandlerFunc doesn't return a function which returns AppError.

Another question I have, how can I avoid explicitly returning `nil` if if I use AppError as the return value?

Note that I get this error:

> cannot use func literal (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
>   AppError) as type http.HandlerFunc in return argument

Comment: The value `nil` cannot be returned because `nil` is not a valid value for a struct.  I don't code that uses the return value.  The AppError returned value is not used in the question. The solution may be to remove the return value from the function.

Comment: Ok let me try it without returning nil, but what value can I return instead of an empty struct then? AppError was included in the OP b/c I thought it was part of the problem, not sure yet.

Comment: I imagine there is a reason  why `http.HandlerFunc` does not return an error. Its only my guess, but since you have `http.ResponseWriter` its this structs responsibility to raise errors instead of handler returning them.

Comment: Yes I can just throw errors instead of returning them I suppose, with `panic()`

Comment: NO PANIC EVER... (well, maybe in a main func) Go does not have exceptions do not ever misuse panic as a replacement.

Comment: `http.Error()` would be suitable in this situation imo

Comment: An http.Handler is responsible for handling any errors. Possible ways to handle the error are: respond to the client with an error status code; log the error.  The choice is yours.

Comment: I have a defer/recover thing going, if there is an exception, it should recover. And send an http response for the request associated with the goroutine. But yeah maybe returning an error back up the chain of middleware is no bueno anyway.

Comment: If you define a handler interface with an error return value and use that interface in your handers and middleware, then it's possible to return an error back up the chain of middleware.  Some frameworks use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

> that won't compile b/c http.HandlerFunc doesn't return a function which returns AppError.

Why you don't handle error directly in makeUpdate method?

---

> how can I avoid explicitly returning nil if if I use AppError as the return value?

Cannot use 'nil' as type AppError in return argument, you can use the **initial value**, like this:

```
func test() AppError {
    ret := AppError{
        200, "OK",
    }

    condition := true // some condition
    if !condition {
        ret.Status = 500
        ret.Message = "internal error"
    }
    return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So instead of returning the status for the request the designers of go give you the [ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter). This is your main interaction with the client. For example to set a status code, do `WriteHeader(500)`.

Answer (score -1):

It's a server and a handler shouldn't return an error, as it was said you should simply notify the client that an error was encountered while processing the request. Determine the error type and output the corresponding http code and optional message body.

Now, if by chance, your server has some other goroutines that need to be notified of the error you can signal to them through a channel (for metrics or things like that), so you can that way use the error in any way you wish outside the handler scope.